# Script to copy auth keys to remote servers needs password four times

Tags: ssh, bash

I work on multiple servers through ssh. I have automated the copying of ssh auth keys with the script below.

The only problem is it asks for the remote servers password 4 times.

How can I change this to ask just once.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# Usage:
#     copy-ssh-key.sh example.com
#

echo -e "\n>>> Creating remote .ssh folder"
ssh -t $1 "mkdir ~/.ssh"

echo -e "\n>>> Updating .ssh folder permissions"
ssh -t $1 "chmod 700 ~/.ssh"

echo -e "\n>>> Copying Auth Keys"
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh $1 "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

echo -e "\n>>> Updating auth keys permissions"
ssh -t $1 "chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: `man ssh-copy-id`. Your problem has been solved.

Comment: Thanks! Googled and googled and did not find this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that SSH on the remote server uses your shell (e.g. `bash`) to run the commands.  So this will work:

```
echo "\n>>> running commands"
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -t $1 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

(Because the commands prior to `cat` don't read from STDIN, `cat` gets the input.)